# Linux file dirty page write back order

Tags: linux, file

In Linux, for a single file what is the dirty page write back(to disk) order ? is it from beginning to end ? or out of order ?

Scenario 1 : without overwrite

A file(in disk) is created and large amount of data written (sequentially) quickly. Now I presume these would be in multiple page caches. When writing back the dirty pages is pages written back in order ?

e.g. Say server shutdown before file write completion.

Now after reboot can we have the disk file in below state

> |--correct data --|---data unset/garbage--|--correct data--|

i.e. I understand last set of bytes in file can be incomplete, but can data in mid be incomplete

Scenario 2 : with overwrite (attempt to use file similar to a circular/ring buffer)

1. File created, data written, after reaching a max size, "fsync"
   called (i.e. data+meta data synchronized).
2. Now, file pointer is
   moved to the beginning of the file and data written sequentially.
   (No fsync done)

Now due to a server shutdown can we have the disk file in below state after reboot

> ```
> |--Newly written data--|--Old data--|--New data--|...
> ```

i.e. for new data, some pages were written to disk out of order

OR

can I assume it is always

> |--Newly written data--|----Newly written data--|--Old data--|

i.e. old data and new data will not mix-up (if present old data would only be at the end of file)